# _init() after instancing a scene

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have two scenes. A disorder scene that acts as a class and a disorder*s* scene that initiates all the disorders.

Disorder.gd

```
extends Node2D

var disorder_name
var disorder_cause
#-----------------Vitals------------------------
var pulse
var O2
var respirations
var systolic
var diastolic
var temperature
var blood_sugar

func _init(disorder_name, cause, pulse = 0, O2 = 0, respirations = 0, systolic = 0, diastolic = 0, temperature = 0, blood_sugar = 0):
    disorder_name = disorder_name
    disorder_cause = cause
    pulse = pulse
    O2 = O2
    respirations = respirations
    systolic = systolic
    diastolic = diastolic
    temperature = temperature
    blood_sugar = blood_sugar
```

Disorders.gd

```
extends Node2D

var disorder = preload("res://Scenes/Disorder.tscn")

func _ready():
    var influenza = disorder.instance()
    influenza._init(temperature = 5)
```

I get

> error(7, 30): Unexpected assign.

I am not sure how to `_init()` the `Disorder` class in `Disorders` to be able to assign only affected params based on the `Disorder` instancing.
`temperature = 5` would add 5 degrees to the person's normal temperature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GDScript do not support named parameters**.

Which means you cannot skip them.

If you really want to go for it, you could use a dictionary:

```
func _init(disorder_name, cause, params := {}):
    self.disorder_name = disorder_name
    self.disorder_cause = cause
    pulse = params.get("pulse", 0)
    O2 = params.get("O2", 0)
    respirations = params.get("respirations", 0)
    systolic = params.get("systolic", 0)
    diastolic = params.get("diastolic", 0)
    temperature = params.get("temperature", 0)
    blood_sugar = params.get("blood_sugar", 0)
```

Which you would use like this:

```
var influenza = disorder.instance()
influenza._init("influenza", cause, {temperature = 5})
```

*I don't know what you would put on `cause`, but notice it was not optional.*

---

However, given that your default values are zero, it is much simpler to just set them after `_init`. So `_init` can be:

```
func _init(disorder_name, cause):
    self.disorder_name = disorder_name
    self.disorder_cause = cause
```

And then:

```
var influenza = disorder.instance()
influenza._init("influenza", cause)
influenza.temperature = 5
```

You can, of course, set default values on the declarations, for example:

```
var pulse = 0
```

---

On a similar note, I want to point out that **GDScript supports types**. Use them.

This is a Variant:

```
var pulse
```

This is a Variant with value `0` (int):

```
var pulse = 0
```

This is a Variant with value `0` (float):

```
var pulse = 0.0
```

This is a float with value `0`:

```
var pulse:float = 0
```

This is an int with value `0`:

```
var pulse:int = 0
```

This is a float with value `0` (the default value):

```
var pulse:float
```

This is an int with value `0` (the default value):

```
var pulse:int
```

This is an int with value `0` (using type inference):

```
var pulse := 0
```

This is a float with value `0` (using type inference):

```
var pulse := 0.0
```